# skip_filter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a site with a coming soon page -- it's managed by a boolean value in the database and a method the application controller called by a `before_filter`.

```
def is_it_live?
   @setting = Setting.find(1)

   if @setting.is_it_live
     return true
   else 
     unless admin_signed_in? 
       redirect_to comingsoon_path
     end
   end
 end
```

I tried to use `skip_filter` on the specific controllers that should be public if the site isn't live, specifically the one that's for `comingsoon` ... but it's not working. I'm getting a redirect when I go to the comingsoon path because it's still running the before_filter in the application controller. Anyway to fix this? Or a better way to handle the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem. I was also declaring `is_it_live?` as a helper method to use the logic in the views, so the problem might be that the filter was still getting called by the view (though it seems if the controller for the view is removing it from the filter chain, it should be removed the view, too? but maybe my thinking is just way off on that), taking it out fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

weird, did you try:

```
skip_before_filter :is_it_live, :only => [:action1, :action2]
```

Comment: Yeah ... and I swear everything was working fine the last time I checked.

Comment: that's crazy, are you sure of your routes?

Comment: Yeah, at least I think: `comingsoon  /comingsoon(.:format)                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"temporary"}`

Comment: I also use it in my admins_sessisions controller for signing in admins and it's not working there, either.

Comment: and so you wrote: `skip_before_filter :is_it_live, :only => [:index]`  in the `temporary` controller?

Comment: yes, and also skip_filter, which is apparently for Rails 3. But I'm using 3.1 ... so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I fear it's related to Rails 3.1 which is not officialy released so bugs could remain... :(